# Python command-line one-liner using xmltodict to convert XML to JSON

Tags: python, json, xml, xmltodict

I am trying to write a Python one-liner using xmltodict to convert an XML file to JSON. It seems like there's an issue reading from *sys.stdin* directly or as *sys.stdin.buffer.read()*:

```
python -c 'import xmltodict, sys, json; json.dump(xmltodict.parse(sys.stdin, process_namespaces=True), sys.stdout, indent=4);' < foo.xml > bar.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `read()` stdin - right now you're just trying to parse the underlying `TextIOWrapper`:

```
python -c 'import xmltodict, sys, json; json.dump(xmltodict.parse(sys.stdin.read(), process_namespaces=True), sys.stdout, indent=4);' < foo.xml > bar.json
                                                                            ^-- Here
```